# Why Am I getting and How can I overcome this Exception to work my Program fine "Exception in thread "Thread-7" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException"

Tags: java, multithreading

I have this `class` **PlayTone** which has this `Thread` to play `MP3` songs with a help of a `Library` called `jLayer`.

```
 public static class PlayTone extends Thread{

            public void run() {

                while (true) {
                    try {

                        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(jLabel12.getText());
                        Player playMP3 = new Player(fis);

                        playMP3.play();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("PLAY TONE");
                        //e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }



}
```

I have this other class calling the above **PlayTone** class. Below you can see that class too

```
public class PlayAlarmWhenTheTimeIsRight extends Thread {
    private volatile  boolean running = true;
    final playTOne pt = new playTOne();
    String textsOfAllLabels = jLabel4.getText() + jLabel7.getText() + " " + jLabel8.getText();
    String first = textsOfAllLabels.substring(0, 5);
    String second = textsOfAllLabels.substring(6, 9);

    final String ifTime = first + second;

    public void run() {

        while (running) {
            if (ifTime.contains(jLabel11.getText())) {

                pt.start();
            } else if(jButton4.isEnabled()==false){
                System.out.println("shutodown");
                shutdownThisThread();

            }else{

            }

        }
    }
    public void shutdownThisThread() {
        running = false;
    }

}
```

But when I run this program it `Throws` an `Exception` as below.

```
    Exception in thread "Thread-7" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException

    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:705)
    at AlarmClock$PlayAlarmWhenTheTimeIsRight.run(AlarmClock.java:675)
```

**Can anyone please tell me what's the wrong with my code???**

Comment: Which line is line 675 in `AlarmClock.java` ?

Comment: My guess is that when the `while` loop comes around a second time, it calls `pt.start()`, but `pt` was already started on the first loop.

Comment: To expand on bradimus' comment: even if you'd stop `pt` you can't restart it - Java doesn't support restarting threads. Instead you'd have to create a new one. From the JavaDoc (which btw you should read) on `Thread#start()`: "It is _never legal to start a thread more than once_. In particular, a thread _may not be restarted_ once it has completed execution."

Comment: @Thomas: This is the 675th line sir: ---> **pt.start();**

Comment: @bradimus: May be the **break;** would do that right?

Comment: To break out of the while-loop? That should prevent the error. I don't know what your requirements are, so I can't know if that will preserve the functionality you want.

Comment: It would probably be better to listen for `jLabel11`'s text to change rather than constantly polling it.